# Get vector of indexes containing values between two numbers

Tags: matlab, vector, slice

I have a vector called `time`, which contains time values.  I'd like obtain a vector of indexes of `time` in which the value is between threshold `x` and threshold `y`.

This is undoubltedly trivial to do, but I'm struggling with Matlab syntax a bit, here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Blz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
time=5:20
idx = find(time > 10 & time < 15) % indices
values=time(time(:)>10 & time(:)<15) % values
```

which give

```
time =

     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20


idx =

 7     8     9    10


values =

    11    12    13    14
```

Comment: @Frank Dernoncourt,  I spoke too quickly (i.e.:  before testing!).  THis doesn't seem to work.  In your code, we're returning the *value* of `time` and not the index.  That said, I've fixed your code, so I'll accept this answer anyway.  The solution is `idx = find(time(:) > 10 & time(:) < 15)`

Comment: oops sry, seems like I had also spoken too quickly. I am going to edit my answer so that other people don't get misled by my initial answer.

Comment: Usage of `find` and `(:)` is redundant, `time(time > x & time < y)` will suffice.